# Can't run Detox tests since React Native 0.61

Tags: reactjs, react-native, detox

My team initially made some E2E tests using Detox when we were using React Native 0.59 on our app. Since then, we upgraded to React Native 0.61 and we are unable to launch the tests.

The build process works fine but it's during the tests launch that it fails.

Here is what I get when I try to run the test. The corresponding emulator doesn't even start and all the tests turn red with this very message:

```
FAIL e2e/firstTest.spec.ts
● Test suite failed to run

ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined

  22 | });
  23 | 
> 24 | afterAll(async () => {
     |                               ^
  25 |   await adapter.afterAll();
  26 |   await detox.cleanup();
  27 | });

 at Object._callee3 (init.js:24:31)
```

We are using React Native 0.61.2, Typescript (for the app's code and even the tests' code) and Detox 14.6.1.

Did somebody ever had this problem and has found a solution for it?

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Victor How is your issue going? I just started using and installing Detox in my project but can not get it running with android. Do you have the same problem?